# terminal emacs run a subprocess in foreground

Tags: emacs, terminal

I am inside terminal emacs.

I'd like to run ranger in foreground.

However, the following code doesn't work:

(call-process "/usr/bin/ranger")

Note, I don't want emacs to simulate a pty (e.g., ansi-term) for ranger. I want the ranger run in my real pty, the one where my emacs resides in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if what you want is possible.  Normally you'd do `M-x suspend-frame`, which will drop you to the shell, run whatever program, and then `fg` to bring back Emacs.  You might be able to do this with something like tmux or screen, but I'm not very familiar with them.